# How to process 2 GeoDataFrames by rows pairwise?

Tags: geopandas, pandas

I have 2 GeoDataFrames 100 records each, and want to calculate distances between respective geometries (Points, of course).

I can't see how to make it other than write a cycle to iterate rows directly. (It seems that something changed since summer, when GeoPandas 0.4 was realeased.)

Here are the ways I used to do it:

**Option 1:** I assign another column. Now it sometimes turns all `Point`s into `nan`.

```
main_df['geometry_other'] = other_df['geometry']
main_df['dist'] = main_df.apply(lambda r: r['geometry'].distance(r['geometry_other']), axis=1)
main_df.drop('geometry_other', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

**Option 2:** I join the 2 geodataframes and do the same. Same way, it turns `'geometry_other'` into `nan`s.

```
main_df = main_df.join(other_df, rsuffix='_other')
# then same as before
```

**Option 3:** Here's what I came up with now, after posting the question. I still don't like the repetitive `.tolist()` on both sides.

```
main_df['match_distance'] = [a.distance(b)
    for a, b in
       zip(main_df['geometry'].tolist(),
           other_df['geometry'].tolist())]
```

What are the options now to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the two GeoDataFrames are "aligned" (same length with same index), you can actually directly use the `distance` method: this accepts another GeoSeries or GeoDataFrame, and then the distance will be calculated elementwise between both series.

With:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

main_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'a' : [1, 2], 'geometry': [Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1)]})
other_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame({'b' : [.1, .2], 'geometry': [Point(1, 0), Point(3, 1)]})
```

gives:

```
In [90]: main_df
Out[90]: 
   a     geometry
0  1  POINT (0 0)
1  2  POINT (1 1)

In [91]: other_df
Out[91]: 
     b     geometry
0  0.1  POINT (1 0)
1  0.2  POINT (3 1)

In [92]: main_df.distance(other_df)
Out[92]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
```

(and `main_df.geometry.distance(other_df.geometry)` does the same)

Note that the `apply` version you show (option 1) should also work, but is thus  not needed / more verbose than the solution above.